# angular *ngIf check if last option in a select tag is selected

Tags: angular

I am implementing a survey into my web application and I would like to take advantage of Angular's Forms via FormsModule. In particular, I have a `<select>` tag that prompts the user to select their favorite fruit. If their favorite fruit doesn't appear in the select, they can choose the `'Other'` option and an addition form will appear below prompting the user to enter their favorite fruit. When the user clicks the 'Add' button, their input will be recorded in the global form as if he/she selected it, but it won't appear in the select as an option. I found a nifty way of displaying the user's favorite in the select itself to show that their input was indeed recorded.

> Is there a way to display that extra form when the last option in the select is selected, **without** using a template reference on the manually coded last option. Ideally I would like to use *ngFor to generate ALL the options in the select, but currently I am manually coding the **last** 'Other' option, that when selected will open another div (via *ngIf).

Here is my fruit-survey.component.html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Fruit Survey</h1>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #surveyForm="ngForm">
      {{diagnostic}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fruit">What is your favorite fruit?</label>
      <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.favoriteFruit" name="favFruit" #favFruit="ngModel">
        <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
        <option class="otherFruitOption" hidden>{{otherFruitOption}}</option>
        <option *ngFor='let choice of fruitChoices'>{{choice}}</option>
        <option #otherFruit>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="otherFruit.selected">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #otherFruitInput>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="(otherFruitInput.value) ? updateSelect(otherFruitInput.value, otherFruit) : ''">Add</button>
      <br />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my fruit-survey.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Survey } from './Survey';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fruit-survey',
  templateUrl: './fruit-survey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fruit-survey.component.css']
})
export class FruitSurveyComponent implements OnInit {

  submitted = false;
  model = new Survey('');
  fruitChoices: string[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Grape', 'Orange', 'Watermelon'];
  otherFruitOption: string;

  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
  }

  updateSelect(fruit: string, otherFruit: any) {
    fruit = fruit.trim();
    this.model.favoriteFruit = fruit;
    this.otherFruitOption = fruit;
    otherFruit.selected = false;
  }

}
```

I just started learning Angular a couple of months ago and I know that the way I implemented all of this is 'hacky' and probably not perfect, so any advice on restructuring the code will be a bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can associate a template reference variable to the `select` element, and test if `selectedIndex` corresponds to the last option index:

```
<select #fruitList ...>
  ...
  <option *ngFor='let choice of fruitChoices'>{{choice}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="fruitList.selectedIndex === fruitList.options.length - 1">
  ...
</div>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwswyn) for a demo.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the last item of the list in an `*ngFor` via

```
*ngFor="let item of list; let isLast = last;"
```

You can now check

```
*ngIf="isLast"
```

**Note**

In Angular 5 or Angular 6, the syntax is

```
*ngFor="let item of list; last as isLast;
```

Comment: will the index variable scope to the div that is outside the div containing the select?

Comment: What about the *ngFor="let item of list; let lastItem = last"?

Comment: @SemirDeljić Cheers!