# Conditional dropdown feature component rendering in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to render some feature components using angular using the dropdown as the selector for them. I am getting errors with the following implementation. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

My Component:

```
interface Sample {
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  samples: Sample[] = [
    {viewValue: 'Sample1'},
    {viewValue: 'Sample2'},
  ];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}
```

My HTML:

```
  <div>
    <h2>Sample:</h2>
    <form>
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Sample</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option *ngFor=" let sample of samples" [value]="sample.viewValue">
            {{sample.viewValue}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div [ngSwitch]="sample.viewValue">
    <app-sample1 *ngSwitchCase="{viewValue: 'Sample1'}"></app-sample1>
    <app-sample2 *ngSwitchCase="{viewValue: 'Sample2'}"></app-sample2>
  </div>
```

Comment: you may want to rename `app-sample1` et al. to `component-to-be-displayed` for better readability (but that's just my opinion!)

Comment: The ngSwitch cannot be outside the ngFor because the "sample" variable only exists within the scope of the ngFor.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663803/angular-ngif-check-if-last-option-in-a-select-tag-is-selected) question on conditionally showing HTML might be helpful..